# Beautiful Soup remove first appearance after selector

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use Beautiful Soup to remove some HTML from an HTML text.

This could be an example of my HTML:

```
<p>whatever</p><h2 class="myclass"><strong>fruit</strong></h2><ul><li>something</li></ul><div>whatever</div><h2 class="myclass"><strong>television</strong></h2><div>whatever</div><ul><li>test</li></ul>
```

Focus on those two elements:

- `<h2 class="myclass"><strong>television</strong></h2>`
- `<ul>`

I am trying to remove the first `<ul>` after `<h2 class="myclass"><strong>television</strong></h2>`, also if it's possible i would like to remove this `<ul>` only if it appears 1 or 2 element after that `<h2>`

Is that possible?

Comment: So you want to remove `<ul><li>test</li></ul>`?

Comment: Right, but `<li>` inside the `<ul>` could be different

Comment: The text can be different? or it might not contain an `<li>` at all?

Comment: it contains <li> but a variable numbers and the the text inside li can be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the second `<h2>` tag using a CSS Selector: `h2:nth-of-type(2)`, and if the [`next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) or the [`next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) after that is an `<ul>` tag, than remove it from the HTML using the [`.decompose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) method:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<p>whatever</p><h2 class="myclass"><strong>fruit</strong></h2><ul><li>something</li></ul><div>whatever</div><h2 class="myclass"><strong>television</strong></h2><div>whatever</div><ul><li>test</li></ul>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

looking_for = soup.select_one("h2:nth-of-type(2)")

if (
    looking_for.next_sibling.name == "ul"
    or looking_for.next_sibling.next_sibling.name == "ul"
):
    soup.select_one("ul:nth-of-type(2)").decompose()

print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```
<p>
 whatever
</p>
<h2 class="myclass">
 <strong>
  fruit
 </strong>
</h2>
<ul>
 <li>
  something
 </li>
</ul>
<div>
 whatever
</div>
<h2 class="myclass">
 <strong>
  television
 </strong>
</h2>
<div>
 whatever
</div>
```

Comment: This is working!! I changed it a bit because `<h2> television` is not always the second `h2` in the text

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS selector (adjacent sibling selector `+`) and then `.extract()`:

```
for tag in soup.select('h2.myclass+ul'):
    tag.extract()
```

If you want to extract all adjacent `ul`s then use `~` selector:

```
for tag in soup.select('h2.myclass~ul'):
    tag.extract()
```